# Exporting to epub - keep text on path editable

Tags: adobe-indesign, svg, xml, epub, accessibility

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

I need to export files from InDesign to an epub format. I am using the built-in export feature of InDesign CC 2015.

It works pretty well, but I have problems with exporting text on paths - any curved/bended text is converted into the background graphic and it's not editable.

In the xhtml I would need it to be represented as an SVG inside the page with the text placed in the  elements. In other words, it needs to be selectable in the web browser, because this will need to be used in readloud epubs where we need to be able to apply styles to elements.

So, what would be the process (regardless whether involving external tools or not) of exporting such a content?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Since indesign is clearly outputting the text as a graphic, then you might want to have a look at this and see if it solves your issue regarding machine readability: http://diagramcenter.org/59-image-guidelines-for-epub-3.html

Answer (score 1):

epub are like very basic websites.

You'll probably need to do that curved text manually by modifying the css/html of your epub after exporting it if InDesign doesn't make that text "readable."

It's possible it might not work either, some CSS customizations are not recognized by e-readers. To modify the epub kindle file and its content, you can use software such as "Calibre", it's free. To modify the CSS/html you can use whatever you feel comfortable with; it could be Dreamweaver or opening the css/html in a text editor.

If you decide to use a svg, you could have a look at these posts below and insert your svg manually in your epub as well; there's a few ways to do it but for epub, you're limited. One thing though, it's possible it won't work well on some e-readers or screen readers.

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

http://schepers.cc/authoring-accessible-svg

https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/

The only other option might be to use a straight line of text if you don't want to insert any code yourself and export only from Indesign. That would be safest option as well even though it's not the fanciest!

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, modifying the content is not an option (it's not my content).

Comment: Would it work to have the text as a white hidden line near the image? Then you wouldn't be able to select it but maybe it will be read aloud?

Answer (score -3):

ePub is not an editable format. You can consider it to be a piece of paper you are printing to. In the same way that it is not possible to print to paper from InDesign and then load that paper back into InDesign for editing, it is not possible to roundtrip ePub either.

PDF is specifically designed for this purpose. It can maintain editable vectors and even store the whole InDesign document.

If you have to use ePub and you want the reader to be able to get at the editable document, what you do is zip the InDesign document, put it on a Web server, and then put a hyperlink in the ePub text that points to the zip file. This is the equivalent of putting a CD in the back of a print book.

Comment: Oh dear, you are so wrong:)

Comment: I agree — so wrong. I must have completely misunderstood this question or maybe this answer was meant for another question and I accidentally put it on the wrong page. I thought it was about shipping an ePub where the user of the ePub would be able to open the ePub document in InDesign without losing any fidelity from the original InDesign document. Of course ePub is editable with Web tools, but its not a good way to do an InDesign workflow.